# Как удалить одинаковые строки в sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть бот, который добавляет данные, введенные пользователем в базу данных, но возникла потребность удалять одинаковые значения, чтобы не засорять эту самую базу данных
При попытке это провернуть вот таким способом:

```
if '/подписка' in body:
    body=body[10:]
    id = [(user_id,body)]
    conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO id VALUES (?,?)", id)
    conn.commit()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM id WHERE channels=?"
    cursor.execute(sql,[(body)])
    cursor.executemany("""DELETE FROM id WHERE ROWID NOT IN(SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM id GROUP BY user,channels)""")
    message =('Ок, жди новых уведомлений', str(cursor.fetchall()))
    conn.close()
    return message, ''
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Подскажите, в чем ошибка? Может, надо удалять каким-то иным методом?

Comment: *Выдает такую ошибку* Вы бы хоть указали, в каком именно операторе... но скорее всего проблема в `executemany` - в тексте два плейсхолдера, но параметр передаётся один. PS. У Вас точно имя таблицы - `id`?

Comment: Да, ошибка в `executemany`, забыл указать (новенький просто), и таблица называется именно `id`

Comment: Надо сказать, что в `SQLite` строки регистрозависимы, т. е. записи типа `Ваня` и `ваня` он при группировке будет считать разными.

Comment: Для большего понимания опишу таблицу: в ней содержится только два столбца: `user` и `channels`. В `user` хранится id пользователя, а в `channels` - ссылка на канал, который указал пользователь. Так что по сути, пользователь сам ничего не пишет => регистр везде одинаков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `executemany` предполагает 2 параметра:

1. Текст SQL оператора с заполнителями вместо значений аргументов
2. Список наборов аргументов
   При вызове выполняется SQL для каждого набора аргументов.

В данном случае `executemany` не нужен - достаточно просто `execute`